# Cannot write from into remote HDFS using flume

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, flume

I am trying to write text into remote machine's HDFS using flume. But my attempts failed.

I am using cloudera quickstart VM as remote machine. 
Here are my steps:

1. I've launched flume as:

   ```
   sudo init.d/flume-ng-agent start
   ```
2. Edited flume config in cloudera manager

   ```
   # Please paste flume.conf here. Example:

   # Sources, channels, and sinks are defined per
   # agent name, in this case 'tier1'.
   tier1.sources  = source1
   tier1.channels = channel1
   tier1.sinks    = sink1

   # For each source, channel, and sink, set
   # standard properties.
   tier1.sources.source1.type     = avro
   tier1.sources.source1.bind     = 172.24.***.*** # address of remote machine (cloudera quickstart VM) 
   tier1.sources.source1.port     = 41414
   tier1.sources.source1.channels = channel1

   tier1.channels.channel1.type   = memory

   tier1.sinks.sink1.type          = hdfs
   tier1.sinks.sink1.channel       = channel1
   tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path     = /tmp/%y-%m-%d/%H%M/%S
   tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream

   #Format to be written
   tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.writeFormat = Text

   tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.maxOpenFiles = 10
   # rollover file based on maximum size of 10 MB
   tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollSize = 10485760

   # never rollover based on the number of events
   tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollCount = 0

   # rollover file based on max time of 1 mi
   tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollInterval = 60

   #Specify the channel the sink should use
   tier1.sinks.sink1.channel = memoryChannel

   # Other properties are specific to each type of
   # source, channel, or sink. In this case, we
   # specify the capacity of the memory channel.
   tier1.channels.channel1.capacity = 100
   ```
3. Here my code which should send messages to remote machine

   ```
   import org.apache.flume.Event;
   import org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException;
   import org.apache.flume.api.RpcClient;
   import org.apache.flume.api.RpcClientFactory;
   import org.apache.flume.event.EventBuilder;
   import java.nio.charset.Charset;

   public class FlumeTransport {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           MyRpcClientFacade client = new MyRpcClientFacade();
           // Initialize client with the remote Flume agent's host and port
           client.init("172.24.***.***", 41414);

           // Send 10 events to the remote Flume agent. That agent should be
           // configured to listen with an AvroSource.
           String sampleData = "Hello Flume!";
           for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
               client.sendDataToFlume(sampleData);
           }

           client.cleanUp();
       }
   }

   class MyRpcClientFacade {
       private RpcClient client;
       private String hostname;
       private int port;

       public void init(String hostname, int port) {
           // Setup the RPC connection
           this.hostname = hostname;
           this.port = port;
           this.client = RpcClientFactory.getDefaultInstance(hostname, port);
           // Use the following method to create a thrift client (instead of the above line):
           // this.client = RpcClientFactory.getThriftInstance(hostname, port);
       }

       public void sendDataToFlume(String data) {
           // Create a Flume Event object that encapsulates the sample data
           Event event = EventBuilder.withBody(data, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

           // Send the event
           try {
               client.append(event);
           } catch (EventDeliveryException e) {
               // clean up and recreate the client
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
               client.close();
               client = null;
               client = RpcClientFactory.getDefaultInstance(hostname, port);
               // Use the following method to create a thrift client (instead of the above line):
               // this.client = RpcClientFactory.getThriftInstance(hostname, port);
           }
       }

       public void cleanUp() {
           // Close the RPC connection
           client.close();
       }

   }
   ```

When I am running application I am getting exception

```
13/2-14:57:14,202 WARN : o.a.f.a.NettyAvroRpcClient - Invalid value for batchSize: 0; Using default value.
13/2-14:57:14,209 WARN : o.a.f.a.NettyAvroRpcClient - Using default maxIOWorkers
NettyAvroRpcClient { host: quickstart.cloudera.*******.com.ua, port: 41414 }: Failed to send event
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Avro RPC Client cannot connect to your flume agent. Check the log files in /var/log/flume-ng/flume.log to find out what happened. It's probable that your agent could not bind to the interface. Consider replacing

```
tier1.sources.source1.bind     = 172.24.***.***
```

with

```
tier1.sources.source1.bind     = 0.0.0.0
```

which effectively binds to all interfaces. Try telnet on 41414 locally to test if the port actually responds.